# .htaccess - Redirect subdomain and path to same subdomain and path on another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have looked far and wide for a solution but haven't been able to find one that resolved my issue.

I am trying to implement a 301 redirect that would redirect the user to another domain, with the same subdomain and path as the one they requested.

i.e. if they land on sub1.domain1.com/page.php they get redirected to sub1.domain2.com/page.php. The redirect should catch ANY subdomain.

I have set the AllowOverride to All on the /var/www/html directory and tried the following but with no luck:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain1.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do realise those lines are commented out?! Otherwise, it looks OK. Although you need to escape the `.` in the `RewriteCond` directive, and perhaps include a position marker to avoid ambiguity. (?) The `QSA` flag is unnecessary here. Note also that 301 redirects are cached by the browser by default so you will need to clear your caches every time if you make a mistake (or test with a 302).

Comment: I had the lines initially uncommented but then added the # to test other variations. However I had no luck with the other pointers you gave. The 302 did not make any difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As w3d mentioned in a comment, the `#` signs need to be removed from the beginning of each line in order for the rules to take effect.

Also, you should update this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain1.com
```

... so that it now looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain1\.com$
```

The `^` sign signifies the beginning of a value, and the `$` signifies the end of a value.

The reason for replacing `(.*)` with `(.+)` is because theoretically you're telling your server that `.domain1.com` is a valid domain name when you use `(.*)` (when in fact there should at least be once character before the first dot).

The reason for the backslashes is to escape the dots inside the `RewriteCond`. See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#rewritecond) for more info on rewrite conditions and rules.

Ultimately you might end up with something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Minor simplifications... There's no need to add anchors around `(.*)` in the `RewriteRule` pattern (although it is very common to see this). `*` is greedy by default so adding anchors just adds bloat. Also, the `QSA` flag is not required here. Unless you are specifically adding a query string in the `RewriteRule` substitution, the query string in the request is automatically appended to the substitution. If the OP is still having problems then make sure that `Options FollowSymLinks` is enabled (ie. `Options +FollowSymLinks` in .htaccess).

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. I have tried the variations but still having no luck. I know the .htaccess file is being read, because entering dummy data triggers a 500 error. When I type in the URL of the first domain with the subdomain, chrome says the webpage is not available. There is no redirect being done at all.

Comment: @RezaKarami That would seem to suggest that you have a problem with the DNS? Are these subdomains already configured? Does your "dummy data" include the subdomain?

Comment: @w3d That didn't cross my mind. Would an A record with a wildcard (*) subdomain suffice? I wouldn't know the exact subdomains since they will be dynamically generated. Thanks

Comment: @w3d it worked like a charm after adding the wildcard A record to the host records. :) Thank you!!!